# Как в питон удалить элемент словаря, сдвинув при этом остальные элементы, следующие за удалённым элементом?

Tags: python, словари

У меня возникла проблема во время написания программы на питон, при реализации функции удаления артикула в словаре образуется пустое место, т.е. в словаре появляется разрыв индексов и перебрать словарь по ключам не получается:

```
{'a1': 'AE1016000|',
 'a2': 'AE1016001|',
 'a3': 'AE1016002|',
 'a4': 'AE1016003|',
 'a6': 'AE1016007|',
 'a7': 'AE1024000|',
 'a8': 'AE1024001|'}
```

Как можно реализовать удаление артикула с последующим сдвигом всех элементов следующих за удалённым на один?
Я пользовался стандартной функцией `pop` и удалял значение по известному ключу

Comment: Вам точно надо перебирать словарь по индексу? Особенностью словаря является отсутствие у него индексов, что даёт другие "плюшки" - зачем вы его вводите? Или вам точно словарь тогда нужен? Живите со списками или кортежами, например. Чем не устроит: `['AE1016000|', 'AE1016001|', 'AE1016002|']`? (а индекс и так есть по умолчанию)

Comment: Если вы перебираете словарь по индексами, то вы неправильно используете словарь. И индексы.

Comment: Мне необходимо упорядочить и синхронизировать между собой 2 больших массива с артикулами и их расшифровками, поэтому я использую словари.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я использую ключи. Неправильно написал)

Comment: Что-то слова "упорядочить" и "словарь" (в Python) у меня не очень стыкуются.

Comment: Я сортирую элементы словаря по возрастанию и сопоставляю им их расшифровку

Comment: Мне это всё кажется странным, так как не понимаю принцип сортировки принципиально неупорядоченного типа данных.

Comment: тут чисто особенности моего проекта и моих способов его реализации)

Comment: @Сергей в 3.6+ словари условно упорядочены.

Comment: Если вы удаляете ключ, то пара ключ-значение удаляется. Никакого пустого места не возникает, потому что в словаре не может быть никакого пустого места и "разрыва индексов".

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо, интересно. И привет автору учебника г.Чернышову, который, описывая реализацию на 3.8. объявил словари неупорядоченными.

Comment: @Эникейщик, относительно "не может быть никакого пустого места и "разрыва индексов"" - у автора вопроса может, так как он ключи словаря в индексы превратил. Они (ключи) у него: 'a1', 'a2', 'a3' и т.д. Так что, удаляя элемент, рушим и эту искусственную индексацию. Объяснено это как "особенности моего проекта и моих способов его реализации". Опыта с Python  у меня мало, но интуиция говорит, что можно было сделать проще. Могу и ошибаться, конечно.

Comment: В целом, проще сделать можно, но изначально задумывающийся функционал был основан на словарях, однако он не был востребован и, следовательно, не был реализован. Переделывать основную механику кода было бы долго, поэтому оставшийся функционал подогнал под словари))) Да и в словарях при проверке работы программы сопоставить элементы по ключам проще чем по индексам в массиве

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def remove_and_offset(dictionary, n):
    keyID = f"a{n}"
    maxID = max(dictionary,
                key=lambda e: int(e[1:]))
    res = dictionary.pop(keyID)
    for i in range(n, int(maxID[1:]) + 1):
        key = f"a{i}"
        if key in dictionary:
            e = dictionary.pop(key)
            dictionary[f"a{i-1}"] = e
    return dictionary
```

Вот так выглядит конечный вариант функции, я отправил запрос на редактирование предыдущего ответа, но правки пока не одобрены, поэтому публикую сюда.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема решается большим <del>и непонятным</del> куском кода:

```
def remove_and_offset(dictionary:dict, n:int):
    keyID = f"a{n}"
    maxID = max(dictionary,
                key=lambda e: int(e[1:]))
    for i in range(n, int(maxID[1:]) + 1):
        key = f"a{i}"
        if key in dictionary:
            e = dictionary.pop(key)
            dictionary[f"a{i-1}"] = e
    return dictionary
```

И ещё: в комментариях было сказано, что здесь списком куда удобнее. Чем он вам не угодил?

Comment: Во-первых: большое спасибо за решение, сейчас разберусь и опробую. Во-вторых: мне необходимо упорядочить и синхронизировать между собой 2 больших массива с артикулами и их расшифровками, поэтому я использую словари.

Comment: Я немного подправил код, теперь он работает как надо: ```def remove_and_offset(dictionary, n):
    keyID = f"a{n}"
    maxID = max(dictionary,
                key=lambda e: int(e[1:]))
    res = dictionary.pop(keyID)
    for i in range(n, int(maxID[1:]) + 1):
        key = f"a{i}"
        if key in dictionary:
            e = dictionary.pop(key)
            dictionary[f"a{i-1}"] = e
    return dictionary``` Первоначальный вариант удалял половину словаря начиная с указанного объекта